# Add ember-cli project to repository

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

After I added my ember-cli project to repository on git, there are some untracked files in node_moduls (there are not js files in node_modules).As I know ember adds necessary files from package.json configuration. But when I try to build this project it writes that could not find ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've used `git clone` to get the repo, you need to install the node and bower dependencies.  These are intentionally left out from the repo when you create a new project with `ember-cli` (see your `.gitignore` file).

Install node dependencies (located in `/node_modules/`):
`npm install`

Install bower dependencies (located in `/bower_components/` or (in 0.0.41 or earlier) `/vendor/`):
`bower install`

Once you've got those installed, then you can `ember build`.